# Should I offer additional help to my supervisor to correct my recent mistakes?

Tags: professionalism, mistakes

I have recently made some mistakes at work which might reflect badly on my reputation as an employee. Nothing similar happened before, I just had a  temporary streak of underperformance. Additional external stress might have played a role in this. Those mistakes were not extremely serious, but significant enough to put me on the radar.

I treated those mistakes as lessons and made adjustments to avoid similar situations in the future, even in case of additional stress. It is  doable.

My supervisor has treated me very leniently and did nothing, but I actually treat this as a sort of favor. I am expecting to get an official reprimand in case I don't correct myself soon.

Should I leave it at that? Or should I go to my supervisor and tell that I would like to repay this with some additional work?

My supervisor is constantly overworked and I often have some free time at work, during which I can't really do anything but sit at my desk and wait. I do get bored and I would like something to do to make the time go faster.

What would you suggest? Is asking for something like this sensible or maybe it could actually reflect even worse on me? I know from observations that when my co-workers make similar mistakes they don't do anything about them (some actually try to cover them).

Also, competition at my workplace recently increased due to raises and I would really like to stay as far away from the bottom of my group as I can.

Answer (score 4):

Your boss clearly has time for you, as he has handled the mistakes in an appropriate way. All you need to do now is perform well for him.

> My supervisor is constantly overworked and I often have some free time at work, during which I can't really do anything but sit at my desk and wait. I do get bored and I would like something to do to make the time go faster.

If you have idle time, you should be asking for more work anyway, so if this is the additional work you are referring to, then realistically you should have been doing this already.

If you are talking about extra hours etc, then no. All he needs from you now is consistently good work. He's backed you when in a slump. Now if you consistely give good results, his faith has been repaid and it will keep you up the ladder.

Answer (score 3):

> Or should I go to my supervisor and tell
>   that I would like to repay this with some additional work?

No.

Work isn't like school where you can do some tasks for some extra credit to bring your grades up.

If you talk with your boss, explain that you understand your mistakes and have taken corrective action, that will usually suffice.

If you have free time when you "can't really do anything" you should be talking to your boss about how you are expected to fill your free time. Perhaps you are expected to sit at your desk and be available, but likely there are always "fill in" tasks that you should be doing.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to repay anyone.

Being a worker does not mean you stop being a human being.  We make mistakes -- the key is to learn from them and not repeat the same mistakes again.

So to answer your question, no, don't do that.  Just do your future assignments well going forward.